# How to properly add and delete div tags with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add/delete a div for every click action made on respective add/delete buttons. but for some reason, when I click on the buttons, nothing happens except that a hashtag is added to the URL and it takes me back to the top of the page.

I'm not sure what is going on. Here is what my code/mark up looks like:

NOTE= I am using foundation 5 (Not sure if that matters)

Javascript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">

        $(".add").live('click', function() {
            var linehtml = $('.line').html();
            var total = $('.line').length;
            var dele = (total - 1);
            $('#linecont').append('<div class="line"><hr />'+linehtml+'</div>');
            return false;
        });

        $(".del").live('click', function() {
            var linecont = $("#linecont");
            var total = linecont.find('.line').length;
            var dele = (total - 1);
            if(total === 1) {
                return false;
            }
            $('.line').eq(dele).remove();
            return false;
        });

   </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <a href="#" class="button add">Add Line</a>
        </div>

        <div class="large-10 columns">
            <a href="#" class="button del">Delete Line</a>
        </div>
    </div>  


<div id="linecont">
        <div class="line">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-3 columns">
                    <label>Status:</label>
                        <select>
                            <option value="New">New</option>
                            <option value="Changed">Changed</option>
                        </select>
                </div>

                <div class="large-3 columns">
                    <label>Product:</label>
                        <select>
                            <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                            <option value="Social">Social</option>
                            <option value="Online">Social</option>
                        </select>
                </div>

                <div class="large-3 columns">
                    <label>Targeting Info:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Type Target Info here">
                </div>

                <div class="large-3 columns">
                    <label>Model:</label>
                        <select>
                            <option value="Mobile">CPC</option>
                            <option value="CPI">CPI</option>
                            <option value="CPM">CPM</option>
                            <option value="CPA">CPA</option>
                            <option value="CPD">CPD</option>
                            <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
                        </select>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is `add` and `del` in the html posted?

Comment: @PSL -- just made an edit. It's there now.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8udWK/2/

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` to add event handlers to dynamically added elements.

Comment: @EbadSaghar One possible reason could be that the events are not registered... Place a debug point Wrap it in `$(function(){//code});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I used jsfiddle too, it worked fine there. But it's not working fine locally.

Comment: @PSL I JUST added the $(document).ready() .... still not working

Comment: see the answer from @Gaby aka G. Petrioli

Comment: @EbadSaghar Check out your script tag. See the second answer you have got.

Comment: @leemo I am using 1.8.3 jQuery. It was deprecated in 1.9 and above.

Comment: @EbadSaghar It was removed in 1.9. It's been deprecated since 1.7

Comment: @leemo I changed it to .on() ... still isn't working...

Comment: Combine both Pedro's answer and Gaby aka G. Petrioli's answer and you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the DOM to become ready. Use jQuery(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".add").live('click', function() {
        var linehtml = $('.line').html();
        var total = $('.line').length;
        var dele = (total - 1);
        $('#linecont').append('<div class="line"><hr />'+linehtml+'</div>');
        return false;
    });

    $(".del").live('click', function() {
        var linecont = $("#linecont");
        var total = linecont.find('.line').length;
        var dele = (total - 1);
        if(total === 1) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.line').eq(dele).remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't .live() deprecated!

Answer (score 2):

you annot put inline code in a `script` tag that also has an  `src` attribute..

Use one tag to include jQuery and one for yor code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
   //your code here..
</script>
```

Comment: @EbadSaghar are you running this from a server even localhost or from a file directly ? if the protocol is `file://` then jquery will not load in the way you include it. You will have to add `http://`